# SQL query - How to achieve the subsequent column updation by summing up the value of current row in Single select query (need to avoid while loop)

Tags: sql-server-2012

The logic which we are trying to achieve in single query is as follows.

1. We need to loop based on row number column. So, on each loop we need to sum-up remaining value and new value.. resultant value to be updated in "by summing up column". and the decimal part to be updated in decimal value column.
2. in next step, need to sum-up the decimal value column by grouping on row number. and the resultant to be updated in remaining value column of next row number
3. the above step 1-2 to be continued till we reach last record.

We achieved this through while loop.. But trying to achieve this without while loop.

Can someone please give idea to achieve this
Please refer the attached image for understanding table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I4Y3.png)

Comment: Sounds like a [homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) No problem with this, but at least please try to provide more details, set up a [mcve], provide what you've tried so far. Doing so, you can be sure, to get help. One hint: Read about windowing functions, especially `SUM() OVER()`.

Comment: Coming by again I see, that you've added a picture behind a link. You might read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try again. Sorry, but nobody wants to type in your data from a picture to set up some show case...